# Why does it take so long to be removed from an email mailing list?

Tags: mailing-list

This question is not site specific, but--what happens behind the scenes which makes being removed from an email mailing list such a lengthy task? All websites which I've visited, if you wish to be added to a email mailing list, will do so instantly. But most of the time, if you wish to unsubscribe from a list, you land at a page saying something along the lines of 'you will be removed from the list within a week'. I can't figure out why it wouldn't be instant. Anyone know?

Also, if this is the wrong place to ask this question, can someone direct me to the right stack exchange site for this question?

Comment: Would it help if I gave some examples? Because that is definitely not true. Plenty of reputable sites with this methodology.

Comment: There's a ton of possible reasons. It all depends on how they manage their list and queue their messages.

Answer (score 1):

Large organisations often do funny things like send their database over to external marketing companies when they send the brief to create the emails. The long turnaround assumes there might be emails 'in the works' that they haven't sent yet, but have included your address in the recipient list.

Another consideration is that bulk emails are often sent in stages to lighten the load on mail servers. Once the send button is pressed, you can't snuff out any single address from the recipient list